# Can someone give me a counterexample to understand why this definition of limit is wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Could someone give me a counterexample to understand why this definition of $\lim_ {x\to a} f(x) = L$, does not work?

> $\forall \delta>0 \exists \varepsilon>0$ such that, if $0<|x−a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)−L|<\varepsilon$

I've searched in this forum and the question has already been made but I don't understand the examples and counterexamples given. I found this: $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x} = 1$, as an example in Spivak Supplement of calculus, but I don´t understand why this example works.

Comment: Any bounded function satisfies your definition, for example.

Comment: Epsilon could be very, very large..

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is bounded,  $f(x)\leq M$ for every $x$. Then, following your definition, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=A$ for every $a$ and every $A$. You give me a $\delta$. I choose $\varepsilon = M+|A|$. Then, if 
$0<|x-a|<\delta \to |f(x)-A|\leq|f(x)|+|A|<M+|A|=\varepsilon$.

(Note that the $\delta$ you chose doesn't even matter, given that $|f(x)-A|\leq|f(x)|+|A|<M+|A|$ holds for every $x$, in particular to those in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$)

Comment: Sorry,but I still don´t get it. Does that implies that epsilon is a big number and that´s why the defiition does not work?

Comment: @Raquelnb Your definition does not guarantee that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are close when $x$ and $y$ are close, in that any bounded function, including for instance functions with jumps, satisfies it. This happens because the fact that $\varepsilon$ is *existentially* quantified means that it is free to be large even when $\delta$ is small.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that
you can get
$f(x)$ as close as you want
to $L$
by choosing $x$
close enough to
$a$.

This means that,
using your notation,
for any $\epsilon > 0$
you can choose a $\delta$,
which is usually a function of
$\epsilon$,
such that 
whenever $|x-a| < \delta$,
$|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

In your logical notation,
this is
∀ ϵ > 0 ∃ δ>0 .
Translation:
For all ϵ > 0
there is a δ>0 
such that
whenever $|x-a| < \delta$,
$|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.